# Wordpress :Error in site title with multi language

Tags: wordpress

I have site with 3 language
1- Arabic
2- English
3- France

The problem is in page title,i set the title for all language like :

> مجمع البحوث العربية

This title work good in Arabic language , but when open as English is show me like:

> طھظپط³ظٹط± ط§ظ„ط¹ط´ط± ط§ظ„ط£ط®ظٹط±

What can do to solve it

Comment: Is your site UTF-8 Encoded?

Comment: yes its UTF-8 Encoded

Comment: check this out: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-easily-create-a-multilingual-wordpress-site/